# How to know Excel file cells count using .NET wrapper for MS Office

Tags: c#, excel, ms-office

In my programm I'm using [.NET wrapper for MS Office](http://msofficefornet.codeplex.com/) for reading Excel file into 2D array.
It works just fine with following code:

```
public static object[,] OpenExcelFileToArray(string filename, string start, string end, int sheetNumber = 1)
{
    using (var app = MSExcel.Application.CreateApplication())
    {
        var book = app.Workbooks.Open(filename);
        var sheet = (MSExcel.Worksheet)book.Worksheets[1];
        var range = sheet.GetRange(start, end);

        return (object[,]) range.Value2;
    }
}
```

In this method I'm sending `string start` and `string end` as the parameters(for example `start = "A1"` and `end = "Z10"`.
It works only if I know already the size of Excel content table.
But what if I don't know the last cell of Excel file?
Could this be resolved using [.NET wrapper for MS Office](http://msofficefornet.codeplex.com/)?
I didn't find requred info on their website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, the Worksheet.UsedRange property is what you're looking for.
I'm not sure, if MS Office Wrapper for .NET offers it.
Microsoft's official .Net wrapper for Office is VSTO, and it supports this property:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608603.aspx